# Add new line to table cell in rmarkdown kable. Linebreak \n not working for latex output

Tags: latex, r-markdown, line-breaks, kableextra

I am creating a `longtable` in rmarkdown, which is text heavy. I'm setting the column width using `column_spec` to space text over multiple lines, but would like to insert manual line breaks to improve the readability. I have followed the advice [here](http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/best_practice_for_newline_in_latex_table.pdf) but still get an error saying the `\n` are not recognised:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.135 Aoike  2018 & H-Ex (12); \nCenter
                                       -Ex (13); \nCon (15)
```

This is my code:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
book1 = read_excel("Table tests/Book1.xlsx", sheet = 1)
book1[is.na(book1)] <- " "
````

````
\begin{landscape}

```{r table,}
book1%>%
 mutate_all(linebreak)%>%
  kbl("latex", longtable = TRUE, escape = F, booktabs =  T, caption = '(ref:exstudies)')%>%
  column_spec(2, width= "5em")%>%
  kable_styling(latex_options= c("striped", "repeat_header"), font_size =10, repeat_header_method =  "replace")%>%
  footnote(general = "some text", general_title = "")
````

```
\end{landscape}
```

This is a **mwe** of my dataframe:

```
book1 = data.frame(Reference = c("Adams 2012", "Aoike 2018"),
                   `Groups (n)` = c("H-Ex (14); Con (15)", "H-Ex (12); \nCenter-Ex (13); \nCon (15)"))
```

Here is the contents of the .tex file:

```
% Options for packages loaded elsewhere
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
%
\documentclass[
  11pt,
]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
  \setmainfont[]{Garamond}
\fi
% Use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{% use microtype if available
  \usepackage[]{microtype}
  \UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{% if non-KOMA class
  \IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
    \usepackage{parskip}
  }{% else
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
}{% if KOMA class
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor}
\IfFileExists{xurl.sty}{\usepackage{xurl}}{} % add URL line breaks if available
\IfFileExists{bookmark.sty}{\usepackage{bookmark}}{\usepackage{hyperref}}
\hypersetup{
  pdftitle={General Introduction},
  hidelinks,
  pdfcreator={LaTeX via pandoc}}
\urlstyle{same} % disable monospaced font for URLs
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,array}
\usepackage{calc} % for calculating minipage widths
% Correct order of tables after \paragraph or \subparagraph
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\longtable{\par}{\if@noskipsec\mbox{}\fi\par}{}{}
\makeatother
% Allow footnotes in longtable head/foot
\IfFileExists{footnotehyper.sty}{\usepackage{footnotehyper}}{\usepackage{footnote}}
\makesavenoteenv{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\def\maxheight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>\textheight\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}
\makeatother
% Scale images if necessary, so that they will not overflow the page
% margins by default, and it is still possible to overwrite the defaults
% using explicit options in \includegraphics[width, height, ...]{}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\maxwidth,height=\maxheight,keepaspectratio}
% Set default figure placement to htbp
\makeatletter
\def\fps@figure{htbp}
\makeatother
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\ifluatex
  \usepackage{selnolig}  % disable illegal ligatures
\fi

\title{General Introduction}
\author{}
\date{\vspace{-2.5em}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

{
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents
}
CKD exercise studies. See Table \ref{tab:exstudies}.



\begin{landscape}

\begingroup\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont

\begin{longtable}[t]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5em }>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5em}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3em}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5em}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5em }>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3em }>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{8em }>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{8em }>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5em }>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5em }}
\caption{\label{tab:exstudies}Exercise studies in patients with CKD. All studies in the table were randomised-controlled trials except Pechter\ldots{}}\\
\toprule
Study  Reference & Groups (n) & Study duration (weeks) & CKD Stage & Other population characteristics & Age (years) & Frequency/ duration & Aerobic & Resitance & Other elements of intervention\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{\textit{(continued)}}\\
\toprule
Study  Reference & Groups (n) & Study duration (weeks) & CKD Stage & Other population characteristics & Age (years) & Frequency/ duration & Aerobic & Resitance & Other elements of intervention\\
\midrule
\endhead

\endfoot
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{10}{l}{\rule{0pt}{1em}All studies in the table were randomised-controlled trials except Pechter... }\\
\endlastfoot
\cellcolor{gray!6}{Aoike 2015} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{H-Ex (14); Con (15)} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{12} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{3-4} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{BMI>25} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{30-50 min., 3 x per wk} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Walking; aiming for VT} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Nil} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Dietary instruction for all patients}\\
Aoike  2018 & H-Ex (12); \n Center Ex (13); \nCon (15) & 24 & 3-4 & Overweight & 56 & 40-60 min., 3 x per wk & Moderate (40-60\% VO2max): home-based = walking; centre-based = treadmill & Nil & \\
\cellcolor{gray!6}{Barcellos  2018} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Ex (76); Con (74)} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{16} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{2-4} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Hypertensive} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{65} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{60 min., 3 x per wk, supervised} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Yes, no details} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Yes, no details} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{}\\
Baria  2014 & Centre-Ex (10); H-Ex (8); Con (9) & 12 & 3-4 & BMI > 25; male & 52 & 30-50 min., 3 x per wk & Centre= treadmill; Home = walking\slash running; HR at VT & Nil & \\
\cellcolor{gray!6}{Beetham 2019} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{HIIT (9); Mod Ex (5)} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{12} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{3-4} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{1+  uncontrolled CVD risk factors (BP, HbA1C, lipids)} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{61} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{HIIT: 4x4 min.; Mod Ex: 40 min. 3 days per wk} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{HIIT: 80-95\% PeakHR, Mod Ex: 65\% peakHR; treadmill} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Nil} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{}\\
\addlinespace
Castaneda  2001/2004 & Ex + low-protein diet (14); low-protein diet only (12) & 12 & SCr 133-442 $\mu$mol/L & Age >50 & 64 & 45 min., 3 x per wk & Nil & 8 reps x 3 sets of chest and leg press, latissimus pull-down, knee extension, and knee flexion & \\
\cellcolor{gray!6}{Eidemak  1997} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Ex (15); Con (15)} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Median 78} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{GFR 10-43} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Non-diabetic} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{44} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{30 min., daily; unsupervised} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{60-75\% maximal exercise capacity, static bike, running, swimming or walking} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Nil} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{}\\
Greenwood  2015 & Ex (8); Con (10) & 52 & 3-4 &  & 53 & 40 min., 3 x per wk (2 x supervised, 1 x home) & stationary exercise cycle; 80\% HRR & Free weights or therabands 80\% of 1RM & \\
\cellcolor{gray!6}{Headley  2012} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Ex (10); Con (11)} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{48} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{2-4} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{55} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{45 min., 3 x per wk, supervised} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{50-60\% VO2 peak} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Weeks 24-48; optional; weight machines} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Dietary instruction for exercise group}\\
Headley  2014 & Ex (25); Con (21) & 16 & 3a-3b & DM or HTN as primary cause of CKD & 58 & 30-45 min., 3 x per wk, supervised & 50-60\% VO2 peak, mixed apparatus & Nil & \\
\addlinespace
\cellcolor{gray!6}{Hellberg 2019} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Endurance \& strength (73); Endurance \& balance (75)} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{52} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{3-5} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{66} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{150 min./ wk} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{2 x 30 minutes; RPE = 13-15} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{3 x 30 minutes; RPE =13-17; 2-3 sets of 10 reps of wither free weight/body weight (resistance) or balance exercises} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{}\\
Hiraki  2017 & H-Ex (14); Con (14) & 52 & 3-4 & Male & 68.5 & 30 min. /day or 8000-10000 steps & Walking & Hand grip, squats and calf raises; 20-30 reps 3x per week & \\
\cellcolor{gray!6}{Howden  2013/2015} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Ex \& lifestyle intervention (36); Con (36)} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{52} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{eGFR 25-60} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{1 or more uncontrolled CV risk factors (BP, HbA1C, lipids)} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{61} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{150 min./wk, beginning with 8 wks 2-3 x per wk supervised in gym; subsequently at home} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Moderate, RPE 11-13} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Whole-body with therabands and Swiss ball} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Lifestyle intervention with dietician and psychologist (sustainable diet and behaviour change for weight loss)}\\
Ikizler  2018 & Ex vs usual activity; Calory restriction vs usual diet (104 total) & 16 & 3-4 & BMI> 25 & 53-58 & 30-45 min., 3 x per wk, supervised &  &  & 10-15\% calory reduciton\\
\cellcolor{gray!6}{Kirkman  2019} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Ex (15); Con (16)} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{12} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{3-5} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{58} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{45 min., 3 x per wk; supervised} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{60-85\% heart rate reserve; cycling, treadmill or epliptical} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Nil} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{}\\
\addlinespace
Kiuchi  2017 & HIIT (25); Mod Ex (25) & 156 & 3-4 &  & 58 & HIIT: 4-30 min.; Mod Ex: 30-60 min. 5 days per wk & HIIT: up to maximal intensity; Mod Ex: 55-85\% max HR & Nil & \\
\cellcolor{gray!6}{Leehey 2016} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Ex + diet (14); Diet alone (18)} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{52} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{2-4} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{T2DM, obese, male} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{66} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{60 min., 3 x per wk; superveised for first 12 wks} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{45-85\% VO2 peak; Treadmill,elliptical or cycle; intervals} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Additional 20-30 minutes/ session} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Nutritional counselling session}\\
Leehey  2009 & Ex (7); Con (4) & 24 & 2-4 & Diabetic, BMI > 30, proteinuria & 66 & 30-40 min., 3 x per wk, supervised for first 6 wks & Walking; supervised sessions were up to 60-84\% VO2peak & Nil & \\
\cellcolor{gray!6}{Miele  2017} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Ex (25); Con (21)} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{16} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{3} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{15-55 min., 3 x per wk, supervised} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Moderate, 50-60\% VO2peak} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Nil} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{}\\
Mustata  2011 & Ex (10); Con (10) & 52 & 3-4 &  & 68 & 20-60 min., 5 x per wk (3 unsupervised, 2 supervised) & 40-60\% VO2peak, treadmill, cycle, ellipitcal trainer; unsupervised = walking &  & \\
\addlinespace
\cellcolor{gray!6}{Pechter  2003} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Ex (11); Con (9)} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{12} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{NA} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Proteinuria; 2+ CV risk factors} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{49} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{30 min., 2x per wk} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Aquatic exercise} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Nil} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{}\\
Rossi  2014 & Ex (59); Con (48) & 12 & 3-4 &  & 68 & 60 min., 2 x per wk, supervised & Treadmill or static cycle; PLE<11(60-65\% HRM) & Free weights3 sets x 15 reps & Provided with pedometer\\
\cellcolor{gray!6}{Small 2017} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Ex + lifestyle} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{52} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{eGFR 25-60} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{62} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{150 min./wk, beginning with 8 wks 2-3 x per wk supervised in gym; subsequently at home} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{4 weeks of group behavior and lifestyle modification and dietary advice}\\
Shi  2014 & Ex (11); Con (10) & 12 & NA & Evidence of CVD & 69 & 30 min., 3-5 x per wk, supervised for first 4 wks & Tai Chi & Nil & \\
\cellcolor{gray!6}{Tang  2017} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{H-Ex (45); Con (45)} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{12} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{1-3} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{45} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{30 min., 3 x per wk, at home} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Walking, cycling jogging; 12-15 RPE} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Nil} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{Exercise education (3 sessions)}\\
\addlinespace
Van Craenenbroeck  2015 & Ex (19); Con (21) & 12 & 3-4 &  & 53 & 10 min., 4x per day, at home & Static cycling, 90\% HR of anaerobic threshold & Nil & \\
\cellcolor{gray!6}{Huppertz 2020} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{}\\
Zhou 2020 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\*
\end{longtable}
\endgroup{}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you a) show the intermediate .tex file so we see which column type is used and b) try with `\linebreak ` (including a space after it)

Comment: @Martin C. Arnold Please don't remove line breaks from TeX error messages. They are the most important part of the error messages because they carry the information at which place the error is. Without the line break how should one know if `\nCenter` or `\nCon` is the undefined control sequence?

Comment: Thanks for the tex file. In the tex file `Aoike  2018 & H-Ex (12); \linebreak Center Ex (13); \linebreak Con (15) & 24 & 3-4 & Overweight & 56 & 40-60 min., 3 x per wk & Moderate (40-60\% VO2max): home-based = walking; centre-based = treadmill & Nil & \\ ` works fine. Can you test with `\linebreak` in your rmarkdown document?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks very much. `\linebreak` appears to be working. Out of interest I've copied the contents of the .tex file (i'm not sure if I've done this right!).  When using `\n` I tried both with and without the space after, neither worked

Comment: I'm not an r user, but if I understand the doc you linked to correctly, the `\n` will only work inside such special r functions like `linebreak("a\nb")`. Anyway, it is definitly not a latex macro for linebreaks.